# Where does Intellij get the javadocs from that show on the tooltip?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

Where does Intellij get the JavaDoc text from which appears on the tooltip in both Java and Clojure?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the -javadoc.jar attached for the jar containing current class Intellij seems to take it from there.

If not, and you have the -sources.jar attached, it will extract the doc from those sources.

Answer (score 0):

It takes javadoc from same place as every other IDE - from... well, javadoc. It reads signature of elements and reads javadoc off them.

If you use code from external jars, you may sometimes need additional jars, that contain javadocs  (same way you need jar with sources for you to look them up f.e. in debugger).